Flutter app cache data not cleared after uninstalling on some devices
I have created a Flutter app, but I'm facing an issue where cached data is not cleared after uninstalling the app on some devices. On some devices, the app data is erased properly after uninstallation, but on others, it remains.
How can I handle this to ensure that all app data, including cached data, is cleared after uninstalling the app on all devices?

Checked app settings and storage: I reviewed the app's storage and cache settings on the devices where the issue occurred. On some devices, even after uninstalling, the app's data was still retained.

Tested on different devices: I tested the app on multiple devices with different OS versions to identify if the issue was specific to certain devices or OS versions. The problem appeared on some Android devices but not on others.



The issued at Auto Backup feature in Android. See here Try turn off it on android manifest:
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"

